# Failed to open stream Google Map API

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, yii2, geocode

I'm using Google Map's API KEY from server-side code to get the Location Name from latitude Longitude. API KEY is not restricted.

It's working while running from local environment, not from live server (Host   x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu). `"allow_url_fopen"` is true in `php.ini` file.

Here's the code i'm using....

```
function GetLocationName($latLng, $apiKey)
{
    try {
        $address = "-";
        $googleApiUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=' . $apiKey . '&latlng=' . $latLng;
        $json = file_get_contents($googleApiUrl);
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        if (count($obj->results) > 0) {
            $address = $obj->results[0]->formatted_address;
        }

    } catch (ErrorException $e) {
        $address = "error";
    }
    return $address;
}
```

I am getting this error now while it's running form live server.

```
file_get_contents(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=apikey=23.736555,90.41355): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: Are your sure `$apiKey` is passed correctly. You should be getting 400 error but you are getting 404. Can you try printing `$googleApiUrl` and then opening it directly in browser

Comment: It's working when running from local environment. I'm getting error in live site.

Comment: Maybe Google is blocking your server's IP address or domain name.

Comment: **is this the exact code?** Did you copy pasted the exact code and the exception? Does not look from your controller. Why i am saying that? because in your function `GeoLocationName` your code above the api url is `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=' . $apiKey . '&latlng=' . $latLng;` where as your error says `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=apikey=23.736555,90.41355` the `latlng` var name is not there where as it should be according to the code ,

Comment: and `404` will be thrown if you dont specify the encoding `json` or `xml` in url @ascsoftw which pretty much seems to be there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with urlencode() like below.

```
function GetLocationName($latLng, $apiKey)
{
    try {
        $address = "-";
        $googleApiUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=' . $apiKey . '&latlng=' . $latLng;
        $json = file_get_contents(urlencode($googleApiUrl));
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        if (count($obj->results) > 0) {
            $address = $obj->results[0]->formatted_address;
        }

    } catch (ErrorException $e) {
        $address = "error";
    }
    return $address;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but URL working fine if i echo then paste and run in web browser.

Comment: There are no special characters in the URL posted.

Answer (score 0):

This Should Works. May be `file_get_content()` not working in server.So try curl code.

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$lat.','.$long.'&key='.GOOGLE_MAP_KEY.');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Comment: It does but not from live server. Error occurring when it's running in live server.

Comment: The `sensor` parameter is no longer required (and hasn't been for years)

Comment: yes, curl also working in local environment, but return null in live server.

Comment: @Naym Please check `phpinfo()` in local and live server.

Comment: "allow_url_fopen" is true in php.ini file.

Comment: You have an extra single quote on second line of code.